# How can i display my menu-bars link to left

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a menu bar in my responsive web site .Currently it is aligned into the right of the web page that i want to show to the left at the marging of `100px` and it should be responsive too but i am not able to do it..

Here is the HTML..

```
       <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#one">What I Do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Who I Am</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work">My Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav
```

and here is the css..

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}

    #nav ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 0.5em;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                height: 3em;
                line-height: 3em;
                padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
                outline: 0;
            }
```

and here is the fiddle demo..Please help me...
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9dd4j1h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/f9dd4j1h/2/)

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5em; /** changed from right to left **/
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}

    #nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0; /** removed default padding ***/
    }
```

Comment: It came .One more addon i want it be aaround 300px; away from left because the place at which it is displaying there i have kept me log..How to do it?

Comment: you can change the left to 300px; if responsive you will need to change it to % or em eg http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/f9dd4j1h/3/

Comment: Ok i did and it is coming fine at `left:150px;` so for this how much % or em i should write?

Comment: it will depend upon the width of log if the log width is fixed then dont give % only give left: width of log

Answer (score 2):

Your question is aprtly to vague to answer in a good way.

First off. You say that you want the menu aligned to the left, instead of to the right. And at a margin of 100 pixels from the left side.
What you need to do is simply change your code from:

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

Into:

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

This sets the element at a absolute position at 100px from the left corner of the page, instead of from the right as you previously had in your markup.

The part about it being responsive will need a lot more css-job done to it. There are several ways to do this. You could either just have it at a automatic width. This will have the width adjust itself according to the elements and the page. Or, you could use the CSS media-screen to tell browsers how to render your element when the browser width is less than or higher than a certain set of pixels.

Hope this helps you in the right direction

Comment: Ok Working but This Menu is not responsive to mobile phone screen size which my previous one was..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Vitorino Fernandes, however, I would recommend avoiding the `position: absolute` on your nav element.  `position: absolute` effectively removes the element from the paint flow, and can cause an overlapping issue with other content.  If you want to keep your navigation stuck to the top of the window, use `position: fixed`, otherwise, floating the navigation left and removing the default padding and margin should get you the effect you're looking for.

```
#nav {
    height: 3em;
    float: left;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    outline: 0;
}
```

I've forked and modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/autoboxer/5nLebzoe/

Cheers,
autoboxer

Comment: Based on your need to offset from the left.  You have two options:  The first is if your log is fixed width, in which case you can use the fixed/fluid layout found here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/.  If your log is a fluid width, you can simply set the width of both the nav and the log using %.